# How to set image be responsive in my case

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that is small but I still need it to be responsive.

I use bootstrap and `img-responsive` class on it.

```
<img class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 img-responsive' id='ball' src='/ball.png'/>
```

My problem is even I use `col-lg-1` the ball is still quiet big in my screen. I want it to be smaller than `col-lg-1` but not sure how to do it in bootstrap. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So basically you want the image to become smaller when the screen size is smaller?

Comment: The img-responsive class scales the image to its parent. How is the parent scaled?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make your own class and then use a Sass breakpoint mixin, like this:::

```
.myImg {
    img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    @include respondto(phone, tablet) {
    min-width:30px;
    max-width:50px;}
```

Just change the parameters to what you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write some CSS.

```
/* replace "@screen-lg-min" with "1200px" if you're not using .less directly. */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { 
    #ball { max-width: 100px; } /* or whatever size you need. */
}
```